# How to display file content in Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, html, ace-editor

I am testing out ace-editor to display large text files from the server.  Since it boasts being able to handle files up to 4 millions lines and has text highlighting, it makes it a good candidate.

I've been struggling to understand the [Document](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=document) and [EditSession](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=edit_session) from Ace Editor.  From my understanding, its possible to tell ace editor to read from a file and display it.

I am using the [createEditSessiont](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=ace)() to create the session and specify the document.  From the api documentation:

createEditSession(Document | String text, TextMode mode)

Document: Required. If text is a Document, it associates the EditSession with it. Otherwise, a new Document is created, with the initial text

Here is my code:

```
<script src="../src/ace.js"></script>
<script>
    var docSession = new ace.createEditSession("../Files/myFile.log", "ace/mode/plain_text");

    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setSession(docSession);
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/dawn");
</script>
```

Unfortunatly, all that appears on the page is "../Files/myFile.log".  I guess it is creating another file with that text instead of reading a document.  How do properly tell it to display the contents of myFile.log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ace doesn't handle files in any way, it is only front-end component of an editor.
Document in createEditSessions definition is an instance of [Aces Document](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/document.js) object, not a file.
To load a file into ace you need to get its contents from the server with ajax call. something like https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.7/demo/kitchen-sink/doclist.js#L164

Answer (score 1):

You don't HAVE to use an ajax call, depending on your app. To play with Ace you can so something simple like this:

```
<?php
   $s = file_get_contents('foo.php');
?>
<div id="editor"></div>
<script>
    var s = '<?= $s ?>';

    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.session.setMode('php');
    editor.session.setValue(s);
</script>
```

Note that you can pass EITHER an element id or an element to ace.edit.

You can display any string content using setValue()

Answer (score 0):

If you use PHP, try this :

```
<div id="editor"><?php echo file_get_contents('your_file_name.php') ?></div>
```

Comment: This is wrong. Ace will overwrite the div when initializing the editor